# Vue: How to avoid using setTimeout in mounted() to wait for props to be available?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I find myself in a pattern of using setTimeout a lot to wait for the initial data to be loaded and available in my Vue components.  Often, I'll be try to access an initial data and it won't be ready.  Example:

```
data: {
  return() {
     name: null
  }
},
props: {
    otherName: {type: String}
},
mounted() {

     if (this.otherName == "Bob" {
        // do something
     }
}
```

Would this pattern work?  I was thinking about this but how often would this fire?  Would I be repeatedly be firing this?  At least with mounted, I know it happens ONCE and only once.

```
computed: {
   getOtherName() {
       return this.otherName;
   }
},
watch: {
   getOtherName(newValue, oldValue) {  
       if (oldValue != null && newValue == "Bob) {
          //do something -- the prop will be null though so I use a setTimeout to wait for it to be available and not null
       }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Watched properties will fire every time there is a detected change to the property, so that solution isn't quite ready. It's good that you're moving away from using timeouts, though, because those are just silly, especially since you're defeating the purpose of Vue being an MVVM framework.

If you want to have an initialization step, then you have two reasonable options:

1. You can mount the component ahead of time and then track an `initialized` flag to determine whether or not you've performed that initialization step.
2. You can defer mounting the component until your data is ready in the first place.

Option 1 will look something like this:

```
data() {
    return {
        initialized: false
    };
},
watch: {
    getOtherName(newValue, oldValue) {
        if(this.initialized || oldValue !== null) {
            return;
        }

        // Perform initialization logic.

        this.initialized = true;
    }
}
```

Option 2 will look something like this:

```
// HTML template
<my-component v-if="data_source !== null" :otherName="data_source"></my-component>

// JS
mounted: {
    // Perform initialization logic.
}
```

Comment: this is great, thanks!  Exactly the advice I was looking for.  Can you just clarify what you mean by using setTimeouts moves away from an MVVM framework -- how is that so?

Comment: @MauirceA The point of an MVVM framework is that rather than tediously tracking down state changes in your data manually, e.g. periodically checking it in a timeout, you instead trigger events, optionally handle certain events that are triggered, and allow the interface itself to merely reflect the current state of your data. Tedious micromanagement like using timeouts to manually detect a change in your data, when the framework itself already allows for automatic detection of such changes, runs completely contrary to that.

Comment: Timeouts do still serve a purpose. For example, maybe you create a component that acts as a loading animation and you need to update the animation's state periodically, e.g. changing the amount of rotation in a spinner. But that timeout is merely modifying data, not attempting to detect and react to changes in it. It's a small distinction, but an incredibly important one. As a general rule, you shouldn't attempt to recreate functionality that the framework already provides, and performing manual state change detections is most certainly recreating existing functionality.

Comment: thanks so much for the detail breakdown of this.  This will help me going forward!